# Convert 32-bit float raster to 16-bit in R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, bit-depth

I have ~100 different 4-band satellite imagery .tif rasters that have floating-point 32 bit depth. I need to convert these to 16-bit unsigned in R while scaling pixel values (not just trashing high values), but I have no idea where to begin for even a single raster, let alone the whole batch. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit with more info: I searched the raster package documentation for bit, pixel, and depth keywords without much luck. Judging by min/max pixel values information found under dataType(), I want to go from FLT4S (32-bit floating point) to INT2U (16 bit). I tried setting datatype with writeRaster() as shown in the example there, but the output was just a black and white image rather than normal satellite imagery.

```
image
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4300, 8909, 38308700, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 691032, 717759, 57492, 70392  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      :        image.1,        image.2,        image.3,        image.4 
min values : 7.244503e-02, 8.278998e-02, 2.286164e-05, 8.571137e-02 
max values :    0.5347134,    0.3522218,    0.4896736,    0.7308348 

dataType(image) #[1] "FLT4S" "FLT4S" "FLT4S" "FLT4S"
image2 = writeRaster(image, 'new.tif', datatype='INT2U', overwrite=TRUE, format="GTiff")
dataType(image2) #[1] "INT2U"

image2
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 4300, 8909, 38308700, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent     : 691032, 717759, 57492, 70392  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : new.tif 
names      : new.1, new.2, new.3, new.4 
min values :     0,     0,     0,     0 
max values :     1,     0,     0,     1
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? What did you try? how would you like to scale? Can you provide a minimal example? Did you look at the help files of the raster package?

Comment: @RobertHijmans, additional info provided in edit. I'm not sure how scaling works mechanistically, e.g. when converting between bit depths in ArcGIS or QGIS, but essentially I'd like every pixel falling within the 32-bit scale to be represented on the 16-bit scale of 0-65,535.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have real values between 0 and 1. By writing to an integer type, these are all truncated to 0. If you want to write to INT2U (unsigned byte) you could first scale the values to be between 0 and 255.

Example data

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
image <- clamp(b/255, 0, 0.6)
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : red, green, blue 
#min values :   0,     0,    0 
#max values : 0.6,   0.6,  0.6
```

What you do (truncation)

```
fname <- paste0(tempfile(), ".tif")      
x <- writeRaster(image, fname, datatype='INT2U', overwrite=TRUE)
x
#min values : 0, 0, 0 
#max values : 1, 1, 1
```

But note the difference when you use rounding

```
fname <- paste0(tempfile(), ".tif")      
y <- round(image)
z <- writeRaster(y, fname, datatype='INT2U', overwrite=TRUE)

s <- stack(x[[1]], z[[1]]) 
plot(s)
```

Now with some scaling

```
maxv <- 65535
r <- round(image * maxv)
fname <- paste0(tempfile(), ".tif")
s <- writeRaster(r, fname, datatype='INT2U', overwrite=TRUE)

#s
#min values :     0,     0,     0 
#max values : 39321, 39321, 39321
```

With your data you would get max values of

```
round(maxv * c(0.5347134, 0.3522218, 0.4896736, 0.7308348 ))
#[1] 35042 23083 32091 47895
```

You can also choose to set the max values of all layers to `maxv`, to keep more variation (but make the values no longer comparable with other data) --- more relevant if you were using a smaller range such as 0-255.

```
ss <- round(maxv * image / maxValue(image))
#names      :   red, green,  blue 
#min values :     0,     0,     0 
#max values : 65535, 65535, 65535
```

the above works because the lowest values are zero; if you have negative values you would do

```
ss <- image - minValue(image)
ss <- round(maxv * ss / maxValue(ss))
```

In other cases you might want to use `clamp`. So you need to decide how to scale

What I showed is linear scaling. There are other ways. For example, there is the is also the `scale` method, to improve the statistical distribution of numbers. That *may* be relevant; but it depends on what your goals are.

Note. You do not say why you do this, and that is OK. But if it is to save hard disk space, you can use compression instead (see `?writeRaster`)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any particular reason why you'd suggest scaling to 0-255 (8-bit) rather than directly to 0-65,535? I'm aiming to use these images for various spectral analyses.

Comment: My bad ---- I was thinking of INT1U  (byte data)! I will fix my answer